# Edge Betweenness Centrality

Tags: python, data-science, data-analysis

I'm new to Centrality measurements. I would like to know how to use the key 'weight' in edge betweenness centrality measurements. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This question is vary broad, and anyone not already familiar with graph theory will have no idea what you're asking. Please [edit] to include a [mcve] with sample data and code for what you've tried so far so that we can provide specific help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am trying to evaluate a road network, I have to consider main roads and weigh the main roads using minor access roads. I thought the "weight" parameter of edge centrality could be used. I would also like to know if there is  another method.

Comment: If you're wanting more discussion about graph theory and the math behind it, mathematics stack exchange or possibly operations research stack exchange might be a better fit. Keep in mind that they will also likely ask for more detail to reproduce your actual problem. Again, for stack overflow, we ask that questions follow a format similar to "Here is my code, here is what I've tried, and here is the error/wrong output". This is not a general discussion site, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, let me see

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.